# Loading IGraphM on a Remote Cluster

Tags: graphs-and-networks, packages, igraphm

I am trying to load IGraphM on a remote cluster at a university. I can load the program, then install the package, which is successful

I then run `<<IGraphM`, and get

[image]

Any advice? The package usually loads fine, it may be the Linux version is incompatible.

Comment: [This](https://github.com/szhorvat/IGraphM/issues) may be a better place to ask this.  The developer might need information about the cluster's operating system, which version of *Mathematica* you are using, etc.

Comment: Thank you, I have contacted the developer with the details.

Comment: Yes, the version of Linux you are using may be incompatible. For interested onlookers: this will be sorted out behind the scenes, and answered here at a later point.

Comment: Ok thank you. Is there some way of loading the new proximity graphs in manually? Without loading IGraphM? That might be a workaround.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I created a new release, v0.3.102, which improves compatibility with various Linux distributions.

- https://github.com/szhorvat/IGraphM/releases/tag/v0.3.102

With Mathematica 11.2 or later, the easiest way to install it is

```
PacletInstall["https://github.com/szhorvat/IGraphM/releases/download/v0.3.102/IGraphM-0.3.102.paclet"]
```

This one-liner is convenient to run on a remote machine. For earlier Mathematica versions, use the [update script](https://github.com/szhorvat/IGraphM#installation) to avoid the hassle of manual downloading.

---

I believe that any Intel x86_64 Linux distro should work for as long as it has glibc 2.14 or later.

The glibc version can be checked by running

```
/lib/libc.so.6
```

Your `libc.so.6` may be in another location. Try `locate libc.so.6` if necessary.

Comment: Thanks. This works well. I was able to install this on the cluster using the usual method.